# Openfortivpn ERROR: connect: Connection timed out

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tunnel

Always get error like this after accidentally unplug power source laptop (and no battery) while `openfortivpn` was running.

```
┌──(user@laptop)-[~]        
└─$ sudo openfortivpn    
[sudo] password for user:        
ERROR:  connect: Connection timed out        
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.        
ERROR:  connect: Connection timed out        
INFO:   Could not log out.        
┌──(user@laptop)-[~]  
└─$ sudo openfortivpn -vv  
DEBUG:  openfortivpn 1.19.0  
DEBUG:  revision unavailable  
DEBUG:  Loaded configuration file "/etc/openfortivpn/config".  
DEBUG:  Loaded password from configuration file "/etc/openfortivpn/config"  
DEBUG:  Configuration host = "vpn.example.com"  
DEBUG:  Configuration realm = ""  
DEBUG:  Configuration port = "10443"  
DEBUG:  Configuration username = "uname"  
DEBUG:  Resolving gateway host ip  
DEBUG:  Establishing ssl connection  
DEBUG:  SO_KEEPALIVE: OFF  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPIDLE: 7200  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPINTVL: 75  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPCNT: 9  
DEBUG:  SO_SNDBUF: 16384  
DEBUG:  SO_RCVBUF: 131072  
DEBUG:  server_addr: 123.45.678.900  
DEBUG:  server_port: 10443  
DEBUG:  gateway_addr: 123.45.678.900  
DEBUG:  gateway_port: 10443  
ERROR:  connect: Connection timed out  
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.  
DEBUG:  SO_KEEPALIVE: OFF  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPIDLE: 7200  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPINTVL: 75  
DEBUG:  TCP_KEEPCNT: 9  
DEBUG:  SO_SNDBUF: 16384  
DEBUG:  SO_RCVBUF: 131072  
DEBUG:  server_addr: 123.45.678.900  
DEBUG:  server_port: 10443  
DEBUG:  gateway_addr: 123.45.678.900  
DEBUG:  gateway_port: 10443  
ERROR:  connect: Connection timed out  
INFO:   Could not log out.
```